# How to create inner children without creating another class?

Tags: java, xml, serialization, simple-framework

I need to generate an XML like this:

```
<Root>
   <Children>
      <InnerChildren>SomethingM</InnerChildren>
   </Children>
</Root>
```

The simplest solution is creating an inner class on the Root class:

```
@Root
class Root{
    @Element
    Children element;

    @Root
    private static class Children{
        @Element
        String innerChildren;
    }
}
```

But I want to avoid that inner class creation, since it will make things look strange while using `Root` objects. Is there anyway I can achieve that result without using inner classes?

#### Expected way to create Root objects:

```
Root root = new Root("Something");
```

What I want to avoid:

```
Children child = new Children("Something");
Root root = new Root(child);
// this could be achieve by injecting some annotations
// in the constructor, but it's awful
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use a normal class instead of an inner class. It should still work:

```
@org.simpleframework.xml.Root
public class Root{
    @Element
    Children children;

    public Root(){
        children = new Children("Something");
    }
}

@org.simpleframework.xml.Root
public class Children{
    @Element
    String innerChildren;

    public Children(String inner){
        innerChildren = inner;
    }
}
```

**Update**: 
If you do not want to create another class, you can use the [`Path`](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/Path.html) annotation by specifying an XPath expression for the `innerChildren` field. For example:

```
@org.simpleframework.xml.Root
class Root {
   @Element
   @Path("children")
   private final String innerChildren;

   public Root(String name){
       innerChildren = name;
   }
}
```

Produces:

```
<root>
   <children>
      <innerChildren>Something</innerChildren>
   </children>
</root>
```

---

Use the [`Namespace`](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/Namespace.html) annotation to add name spaces. For example:

```
@org.simpleframework.xml.Root
@Namespace(reference="http://domain/parent", prefix="bla")
class Root {
   @Element
   @Path("bla:children")
   @Namespace(reference="http://domain/parent", prefix="bla")
   private final String innerChildren;

   public Root(String name){
       innerChildren = name;
   }
}
```

Produces:

```
<bla:root xmlns:bla="http://domain/parent">
   <bla:children>
      <bla:innerChildren>Something</bla:innerChildren>
   </bla:children>
</bla:root>
```

---

If using Styles to format the XML, it's necessary to do some modifications since they remove the `:` from the `Element`. The result using styles is:

```
<bla:root xmlns:bla="http://domain/parent">
   <blachildren>
      <bla:innerChildren>Something</bla:innerChildren>
   </blachildren>
</bla:root>
```

This is what I did:

```
public class MyStyle extends CamelCaseStyle{
    @Override
    public String getElement(String name) {
        if( name == null ){
            return null;
        }
        int index = name.indexOf(':');
        if( index != -1 ){
            String theRest = super.getElement(name.substring(index+1));
            return name.substring(0, index+1)+theRest;
        }
        return super.getElement(name);
    }
}
```

And now the result is the expected one:

```
<bla:Root xmlns:bla="http://domain/parent">
   <bla:Children>
      <bla:InnerChildren>Something</bla:InnerChildren>
   </bla:Children>
</bla:Root>
```

Comment: So... is not other way but creating another class (outer or inner)?

Comment: Also, problem that way is that I would need to do something like: `new Root("Something");`... but in that case, deserialization won't work since SimpleXML won't know how to use that constructor.

Comment: Wow... that's just amazing... just a last thing... what if I need to produce `<bla:children>` where `bla` is a namespace? Cannot find a way to do so.

Comment: @cristian i've added namespaces

Comment: I had tried that, but the result is: `<blachildren>` instead of `<bla:children>` :(

Comment: OK... it was because I was using a Styler, and it removes the `:` from the elements. I will edit your answer to show the solution I found.

Comment: Dude you are a lifesaver, I have been hitting my head on path for couple of hours. I was using "Parent/Child" in path instead of just "Parent" :/